# Can't push variable which is object into the array

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my javascript

```
var inventory = [];
var money = 10;
function buyToInventory(what){
    if(this.price>money){
        log.unshift("D"+day+" "+hour+":"+minute+" - Poor hobo, you can't afford "+this.name+".<br>");
    } else {
        inventory.push=what;
        money=money-this.price;
            updateMoney();
    };
};
function drinkable(name, price, effect){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.effect = effect;
    this.use = function(){
        satisfy(thirst,this.effect,"#thirst")
    };
};
var water = new drinkable("1l water", 1, 20);
```

Problem is when I write this in console `buyToInventory(water)`. It seems like my function `buyToInventory` is totally wrong, it doesnt push water into the `inventory` array or when I set `money = 0`, it doesn't add that message about not having money. I can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Any help will help me a lot. :)

Thanks.

Comment: I think you likely mean to use `what.price` instead of `this.price`. Here, if you really are calling `buyToInventory(water)`, then `this` is the global `window` object inside `buyToInventory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `push`, to push an item into the array, you need to do:

`inventory.push(what)`;

Or whatever part of `what` you need e.g. `price` as mentiond by @apsillers